# Enabling swap takes long time

Tags: linux

HAi Linux,

I am using FC 4 on in my system. When i boot the system it spends more time in enabling swape then it starts normaly. can any one tell me why it is happening and how to solve it.

thank u.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is going to depend on several factors:

- what hardware are you on
- where is the swap partition/file
- what other processes are coming-on at startup?
- etc

My first suggestion would be to update to a much more recent edition of Fedora, if you can - FC4 is pretty old by now, and the community has done **A LOT** in the intervening releases. Current is [F11](http://fedoraproject.org) as of today.

If your drive hosting the swap space is starting to have problems, you'll need to look at replacing it.

You may also consider a real memory upgrade, and reduce your swap size :)